# Applying vectorized multivariable function row by row in dataframe

Tags: r, apply, do.call

I have searched extensively on SO but couldn't find an answer to a problem exactly like mine..

I am trying to generate some time-series entries with a function that reads the multivariable parameters from the `inputs` dataframe. Each set of variables `{x,y,z,...}` from `inputs` generates a time-series dataframe; the collection of which needs to be unlisted.

The `inputs` dataframe itself are of mixed types (characters and doubles) so I have been having issues with the `apply` function which I understand internally converts to matrix object and thus fails. 
`mapply` seems like the ideal candidate (and the procedure *runs* but the results are invalid because the time-series generating function itself is vectorized as it generates a normal distribution)

My code below runs but gives the wrong results

```
library(dplyr)
library(truncnorm)

forecast_curve <- function(case_id,
                           wal,
                           wal_sd,
                           amt,
                           n_qrtr) {

  result <- 
    tibble(case_id = case_id, 
           quarter = seq(1, n_qrtr, 1)
    ) %>%
    mutate(
      amt_qrtr = amt * 
        dtruncnorm(seq(1, n_qrtr, 1),a = 1,b = n_qrtr,mean = wal, sd = wal_sd)
    )
  return(result)
}

#Generate inputs
inputs <- 
  tibble(
    case_id = letters[1:10],
    wal = seq(5,14,1),
    wal_sd = rep(4,10),
    total_amt_FC = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),            
    n_qrtr = rep(12,10)
  )

#outputs function
outputs <- function(){
  tmp <-
      mapply(
        forecast_curve,
        inputs$case_id,
        inputs$wal,
        inputs$wal_sd,
        inputs$total_amt_FC,
        inputs$n_qrtr
      )

  tmp <-
    as.data.frame(apply(tmp, 1, unlist)) %>% 
    tibble() %>% 
    mutate(
      quarter = as.numeric(quarter),
      amt_qrtr = as.numeric(amt_qrtr)
    ) %>% 
    arrange(case_id,quarter)

  return(tmp)
}
```

If one looks closely at the results for `case_id == a` then the results look like this

```
print(outputs() %>% filter (case_id == 'a'), n= 30)

   case_id quarter amt_qrtr
   <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 a             1       80
 2 a             2       65
 3 a             3       52
 4 a             4       39
 5 a             5       89
 6 a             6       94
 7 a             7       95
 8 a             8       96
 9 a             9       95
10 a            10       94
11 a            11       89
12 a            12       80
```

However the correct results for the same parameters (which match the first row in `inputs`) are

```
#Correct example output
forecast_curve('a',5,4,10,12)
   case_id quarter amt_qrtr
   <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 a             1    0.755
 2 a             2    0.940
 3 a             3    1.10 
 4 a             4    1.21 
 5 a             5    1.24 
 6 a             6    1.21 
 7 a             7    1.10 
 8 a             8    0.940
 9 a             9    0.755
10 a            10    0.570
11 a            11    0.404
12 a            12    0.269
```

It would appear from similar questions on SO that the solution is with `do.call` however I cannot get it to work with my case below.

Many thanks in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the problem harder than it is.  Assuming you have a function like `forecast_curve`, you can call the function directly with `mapply`.  There is no need for the `outputs` function.

In your console window, type `?mapply` to have a look at the help for `mapply` so that you can see the parameters required.  `mapply` will call the function specified for `FUN`, passing to `FUN` the first value from every vector in the `...` parameter.  It will then call the function again with the second value from every vector in the `...` parameter.  And so on.  If you set `SIMPLIFY = F`, the result will always be returned in a list.

Since `forecast_curve` returns a tibble, when you `mapply` with `FUN = forecast_curve`, you will get back a list of tibbles.  Thus, the following code will return a list containing 10 tibbles, one for each row of the `inputs` tibble.

```
listOfTibbles = 
  mapply(
    forecast_curve,
    inputs$case_id,
    inputs$wal,
    inputs$wal_sd,
    inputs$total_amt_FC, 
    inputs$n_qrtr,
    SIMPLIFY = F
  )
```

If you want to combine all of these tibbles into a single tibble, you need to use `rbind`, not `unlist`.  You could do it like this:

```
singleTibble = rbind(listOfTibbles[[1]], listOfTibbles[[2]], listOfTibbles[[3]], listOfTibbles[[4]], listOfTibbles[[5]], listOfTibbles[[6]], listOfTibbles[[7]], listOfTibbles[[8]], listOfTibbles[[9]], listOfTibbles[[10]])
```

But `do.call` provides an easier way.  `do.call` calls a function (in this case, `rbind`) using the values in a list as the parameters for the function.  So you get the same result using:

```
singleTibble = do.call(rbind, listOfTibbles)
```

Comment: Marking this as the solution. I'm facepalming to some extent because it looks so obvious now that you have done it. I don't understand however why my approach was yielding wrong results though, I will continue to look into that. I am wrapping ```mapply``` and ```do.call``` in the ```outputs``` function though, as I need to pass it to ```ggplot``` and other routines which need to generate on the fly.

Comment: In `mutate(
      quarter = as.numeric(quarter),
      amt_qrtr = as.numeric(amt_qrtr)
    )` `as.numeric(quarter)` and `as.numeric(amt_qrtr)` return the levels of `quarter` and `amt_qrtr`.  You need, e.g., `quarter = as.numeric(as.character(quarter))` in order for your approach to work.